# How to list HDFS subfolders and files recursively using pyarrow

Tags: python, recursion, hdfs, pyarrow

I am trying to list all the files and folders recursively inside a given HDFS directory. The below code just list the object in the first level. Is there any API to do recursive list?

```
import pyarrow as pa
fs = pa.hdfs.connect()
my_path = "/path/to/folder"
obj_list = fs.ls(my_path, True)
for d in obj_list:    
    print(f'{d["name"]}, {d["last_modified_time"]}')
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an HDFS system available but you should be able to do it with the new filesystem API.  Does something like this work?

```
from pyarrow import fs
hdfs = fs.HadoopFileSystem(host, port, user=user, kerb_ticket=ticket_cache_path)
hdfs.get_file_info(fs.FileSelector("/path/to/folder", recursive=True))
```